# Ubuntu Cinnamon will shutdown (or suspend) if no one logs in

Tags: cinnamon, 23.04

I have an unusual situation: I recently installed Ubuntu Cinnamon 23.04. When I boot the machine, if I don't log in, the machine eventually shuts down (or suspends) and will not wake up with a wakeonlan packet.

I've checked all I could think like the power management settings and I have not found what causes this. At first, i thought that maybe it was a shutdown because of a hardware issue but if I just login (even if it's remotely), the machine will stay on - it only seems to do that when no one is on the machine.

I am at a loss on how to stop this behavior and if anyone has pointers on what I could check,that would be greatly appreciated. I googled for this but I found nothing relevant to my case. I don't need to be provided a solution, just pointers will suffice, i can do the research. :-)

Thank you in advance.
Pierre